# MySQL - How to use subquery into IN statement by value

Tags: sql, mysql, csv, group-concat

The question is to get table column data and use it as a value list for IN function;

For this example I created 2 tables: movies and genres

Table "movies" contains 3 columns: id, name and genre.
Table "genres" contains 2 columns: id and name.

```
+- movies-+
|         |- movie_id - int(11) - AUTO_INCREMENT - PRIMARY
|         |- movie_name - varchar(255)
|         |- movie_genres - varchar(255)
|
|         
+- genres-+
          |- genre_id - int(11) - AUTO_INCREMENT - PRIMARY
          |- genre_name - varchar(255)
```

Both tables contain some dummy data:

```
+----------+------------+--------------+
| movie_id | movie_name | movie_genres |
+----------+------------+--------------+
|        1 | MOVIE 1    | 2,3,1        |
|        2 | MOVIE 2    | 2,4          |
|        3 | MOVIE 3    | 1,3          |
|        4 | MOVIE 4    | 3,4          |
+----------+------------+--------------+

+----------+------------+
| genre_id | genre_name |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | Comedy     |
|        2 | Fantasy    |
|        3 | Action     |
|        4 | Mystery    |
+----------+------------+
```

My goal is to get result like this:

```
+----------+------------+--------------+-----------------------+
| movie_id | movie_name | movie_genres |   movie_genre_names   |
+----------+------------+--------------+-----------------------+
|        1 | MOVIE 1    | 2,3,1        | Fantasy,Action,Comedy |
|        2 | MOVIE 2    | 2,4          | Fantasy,Mystery       |
|        3 | MOVIE 3    | 1,3          | Comedy,Action         |
|        4 | MOVIE 4    | 3,4          | Action,Mystery        |
+----------+------------+--------------+-----------------------+
```

I'm using this query and it's partly working only problem is that it uses the first value of the `movie_genres` field in the IN value list.

```
SELECT `m` . * , GROUP_CONCAT( `g`.`genre_name` ) AS `movie_genre_names`
FROM `genres` AS `g`
LEFT JOIN `movies` AS `m` ON ( `g`.`genre_id`
IN (
`m`.`movie_genres`
) )
WHERE `g`.`genre_id`
IN (
(
SELECT `movie_genres`
FROM `movies`
WHERE `movie_id` =1
)
)
GROUP BY 1 =1
```

The results greatly differ from the one I want:

```
+----------+------------+--------------+-------------------+
| movie_id | movie_name | movie_genres | movie_genre_names |
+----------+------------+--------------+-------------------+
|        1 | MOVIE 1    | 2,3,1        | Fantasy,Fantasy   |
+----------+------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

Sorry if I missed some data I'm new to mysql.

What query should I use to get the wanted results?

Comment: how do u create such beautiful table structure shown on this page.is there any snytax to create table in stackoverflow?

Comment: First one by hand and others by mysql shell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bad design. You should create a `many-to-many` link table `(movie_id, genre_id)`

If you cannot change this design, however, use this query:

```
SELECT  movie.*
        (
        SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(genre_name)
        FROM    genres
        WHERE   find_in_set(genre_id, movie_genres)
        ) as movie_genre_names
FROM    movies
```

Comment: Thanks. Final query looks like this.

SELECT  *, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(genre_name) FROM `genres` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(genre_id, movie_genres)) AS `movie_genre_names` FROM `movies`;