# Mysql query with group_concat in subquery not giving correct results

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have 2 tables:

- category(`inter_archi_cat` table) and their linking with other
- entities(`inter_archi` table )

I want to select only categories which linked to any entity.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM inter_archi_cat 
 WHERE id IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sub_cat) as allcat 
                FROM inter_archi)
```

If I ran the subquery individually, I'm giving correct results (apx 40 records).  But while running with main query its giving only 1 record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it:

here is changed query:

```
SELECT distinct cat.id,cat.name
  FROM inter_archi_cat  as cat
  join   inter_archi as inter on (cat.id in (inter.sub_cat))
```

got idea from

[MySQL - How to use subquery into IN statement by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240136/mysql-how-to-use-subquery-into-in-statement-by-value)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use IN and subquery. You can achieve the same result using simple inner join:

```
SELECT ic.* FROM inter_archi_cat ic 
JOIN inter_archi i 
ON i.sub_cat = ic.id 
GROUP BY ic.id
```

which would be a lot faster.

Comment: I have multiple categories separated by comma under each row under sub_cat column

Comment: I see, then you really need IN, so your own answer is good, but you should change your question to have correct info, so others can learn from it in the future.